# SQL database relational: performance modeling one to many

Tags: sql, many-to-many, relational-database, one-to-many, modeling

I have got a doubt modeling a relational database. I wonder which option is best in design and performance.

First option:

```
 Project         Project_task       Task
 --------         -----------       -----
 id              id_project         id
                 id_task
```

Second option (my doubt):

```
 Project       Task
 --------      ------
 id            id
               id_project   (INDEX)
```

Note: One project can has got many task, but one task only can has got a project.

Maybe the second option is less "relational" but I think it has more performance. I can get all the task of one project quering with a single SELECT without JOIN. I have got a table less than maintaining...

Is the second option a good practice and choice?

Comment: In your first example, isn't your relation from project to projecttask supposed to be onetomany? One project relates to multple combinations of project_task. How can a project_task relate to multiple projects?

About the performance, it is true that with the second example you could query all the tasks for 1 project without a JOIN. However, your task-table would contain a lot of doubles (same task can be in different projects, but will have to be duplicated then with a different id_project), which in turn slows down the performance.

Comment: sorry, it was a mistake in the notation. I will edit the information